# how single process of mozilla can manage tcp ports...?

Tags: networking, browser, mozilla, tcp

In my pc if I open different tabs in IE or Chrome, different processes will be created, so each process can be listening through separate TCP port. So they manage session successfully.

But in case of Mozilla, single process will be created in Operating System, even many tabs are opened! As Mozilla creates multiple threads for multiple tabs, it has only single process id.

If a packet arrives from a web server, My OS will handover it to a particular process, using TCP Destination port number!!!

In case of IE, Chrome there is no issue, as they have different processes for each tab…!
But how Mozilla able to manage different sessions with single process…?

Answer (score 0):

In fact its much simpler when you use threads, tabs are not standalone entries, each page is rendered in firefox core and what you see in the tabs are only representation of data, the view :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to listen for response on severel connection within one process.

Handling multible tabs with one or severel processes is a design choise with pros an cons.